# Appium NOT locating element when java variable is used in xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, appium

I'm trying to locate elements dynamically usign the xpath. However, when I use variable in the xpath, elements are NOT located. However, if I use hardcoded value, elements are located properly.

What am I missing here?

Below xpath locates the elements perfectly:

`driver.findElements(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@value, 'hp')]"));`

whereas, below xpath doesn't locate the elements:

`driver.findElements(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@value, '" + device + "')]"));`

Please note that , there are multiple elements matching the above xpath.

I even tried below code but of no use:

`driver.findElements(By.XPath(String.Format("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@value, '{0}')]", device)));`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the case mismatch in the value returned by variable. i.e; device variable was returning 'hP' instead of 'hp'.

Corrected the code and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try trimming the spaces as:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@value, '"+device+"')]"));
```

Or using `String.format()` as:

```
String device = "hp";
driver.findElements(By.xpath(String.format("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@value, '%s')]", device)));
```

Note:

1. Instead of `FindElements()` it should be `findElements()`
2. Instead of `String.Format()` it should be `String.format()`

Comment: I have tried after removing space. But didn't work!!!

Comment: How about the second option using `String.format()`?

Comment: That was typo here while asking the question. It is' String.format' in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Try do debug this issue as following:
Define the XPath string before calling `driver.findElements` method, format the string to have the proper value and then pass it into Selenium method, as following:

```java
String xpathLocator = "//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@value, '%s')]";
xpathLocator = String.format(xpathLocator, device);
driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathLocator));
```

As about your existing code.
Here `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@value, '" + device + "')]"));`
I can't see the formatting action.
And here `driver.FindElements(By.XPath(string.Format("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@value, '{0}')]", device)));`
it seems to be a wrong syntax.
It should be `String.format` while you wrote `string.Format`

Comment: I tried this. But didn't work for me.

Comment: When debugging, what is the value of `xpathLocator` after string formatting? Is it correct?

Comment: Also, have you seen my updated part of the answer?

Comment: Yes. After debugging, xpath value is correct. i.e;  ```By.xpath: //XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@value, 'hp')]``` is the value.

Comment: So, it looks correct but still not working?

Comment: Yes !1 This is kinda strange for me though.

Comment: Try to look carefully. Should be some difference between the value you receiving here that not working and `"//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@value, 'hp')]"` that is working. It's computing, no magic :)

Comment: Maybe some extra scpace or ` instead of ' etc. I don't know.

Comment: Got it!!! It was lower case and upper case problem. The value returned by variable was hP. Thanks a lot for your help.